# Will my prospective employer contact my past employer after I’ve signed the offer letter?

Tags: job-offer, resignation, employer, employees

I received an offer letter today from a big-name sports organization. However I have to resign from my current job and feel as though though once I resign it will burn a bridge, deeming me “ineligible for rehire” in the event that employer was contacted as a reference. So I wanted to wait until after I signed the offer. What are the chances of the company I will be signing an offer with contacting my past employer after signing the offer?

Comment: Usually they will contact your past employer to verify date of employment and your position. In the US it's not legal to ask about your performance in that position. I don't know why they would contact your old employer after you sign an offer.

Comment: Wait, why is quitting one job and going to the other an issue here? Wouldn't it make sense to _not_ be working two jobs at once? There's a detail in your question about this resignation that's impactful enough to leave an impression on your prior company that you're concerned about reprisal and that needs to be surfaced so you could get a reasonable answer.

Comment: Because I was told if I resigned from my current employer they would mark me “ineligible for rehire”. So I don’t want the company who I will be signing the offer with to reach out to the employer I am resigning with after I sign my offer, and them be told that I am considered a “ineligible for rehire” - and have the impression that I may not be the best candidate after hearing that, or something.

Comment: So your current company is pressuring you to not resign by saying they will refuse to re-hire you if you want to work for them again in the future? I don't think that will make the new company back out of an offer. It might make you more attractive because you can't go back.

Comment: @ColleenV - I have heard for a company to contact a previous employer all they can ask is “if the employee is eligible for rehire”. Just don’t want the company I am signing on with to contact them, and hear that I am not eligible and get a bad impression. But hoping they wouldn’t do that being that I will have already signed the offer. I would hope they would have contacted any previous employers before offering.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yessir it is. I am supposed to be receiving the offer letter tomorrow morning. Once signed and returned do you think that there is a chance they will still reach out to my past employer?

Comment: What country? Some places differ drastically from others; I don't even try to understand India's system...

Answer (score 1):

In the Western context - I'm pretty sure contacting a new employer to say bad things about an ex-employee would result in a very expensive lawsuit for said employer.

To answer the question directly - if they have presented you with an Offer, generally that means any due-diligence on their part (contacting references etc.) has already been completed - so I'd be extremely surprised if they did contact your old company.

However, there is no Geo Tag and the laws regarding what an ex-employer can say varies greatly, in NZ for example - if I'm a referee - I'm free to tell the prospective hirer that you weren't a good worker or that you had issues with punctuality - whereas I believe in the US that is illegal (in some states? Not 100% sure)

Answer (score 0):

> What are the chances of the company I will be signing an offer with
> contacting my past employer after signing the offer?

You have to check the offer letter for any conditions that could cause the new company to revoke the offer. Possible conditions include:

- Criminal background investigation.
- Work history.
- Drug test.
- Financial history.
- Completion of a mandatory certification.
- Final approval of a customer.
- Awarding of a new contract.

If the offer letter doesn't include an item on this list that means either it doesn't apply, or the local law doesn't allow them to check, or that you have already met the requirement.

What you are asking about falls under work history. They will want to know if you ever were fired for cause. They will also be looking for embellishment in your job history. They will also want to know about any gaps in your history.

> However I have to resign from my current job and feel as though though
> once I resign it will burn a bridge, deeming me “ineligible for
> rehire” in the event that employer was contacted as a reference. So I
> wanted to wait until after I signed the offer.

Once you have signed and returned an offer letter that has zero conditions, then you can figure out which day to tell your current employer that you will be leaving.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have had the work history line. I was being hired by a company that had been caught inflating employees resumes. Since the rates they could bill on some contracts depended on the exact level of experience an employee had, some of their government customers required everybody added to their contract have their resume confirmed by an outside company picked by the government. That added 2 weeks to the hiring process. It was mentioned in the original offer letter, plus the letter had the instructions on how to get that process started.